# "show more" directive for angular material autocomplete in md-menu-class

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, material-design, angular-material

I am using angular material autocomplete to show results.Everything is coming perfect except that i want to show only results in set of 10 in the dropdown and then have "show more" kind of utility after the last result in dropdown to handle event to get next 10 results.
Has anyone tried to hook any directive in the md-menu-class template to achieve the same.
Here in my md-autocomplete code in jade

```
md-autocomplete(md-selected-item="selectedItem",md-search-text-change="textchange()", md-selected-item-change = "itemchange(item)", md-search-text="searchText",md-items="item in getautosuggest(searchText)",md-item-text="item.fields.input[0]",md-min-length="3",md-floating-label="Search",hide-sm,show-gt-sm)
                                md-item-template
                                    span(md-highlight-text="searchText",md-highlight-flags="^i"){{item.fields.virgininput[0]}} in {{item.fields.location[0]}} in {{item.fields.identifier[0]}}
                                md-not-found Sorry we don't have matching results for "{{searchText}}"
```

Thanks

Comment: Also looking for this functionality.  Were you able to implement this?

Comment: i moved on to jquery based SPA.